# .htaccess redirect root to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like mod_rewrite to redirect all requests to non existing files and folders, and all requests to the main folder ("root") to a subfolder. So i've set it up like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} / [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my/subfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Unfortunately, it does not work: if i request example.com/public/  it redirects to my processing script (so redirecting to my/subfolder/index.php?app=public ) although the folder "public" exists.
Note that requesting domain.com/ correctly redirects to my/subfolder/index.php

Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it does not work because your last condition is not matching only the root but any uri that has / in it, which is basically everything. Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my/subfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that [NC] is not needed as you are not trying to match any alphabets, so "No Case" is not really needed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937873/how-to-remove-a-subdirectory-from-the-url-when-forwarding-to-sudirectory ?