# How to remove a subdirectory from the url when forwarding to sudirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

On a shared server I am forced to manage document roots of domains from cpanel which is buggy and consumes lots of time. So I redirected all domains to one directory lets say `root`. An example:

```
sd1.domain.com  ---> public_html/web/
sd2.domain.com  ---> public_html/web/
sd1.domain2.com ---> public_html/web/
sd2.domain2.com ---> public_html/web/
```

When user browses these websites, I forward this websites using htaccess rules such as

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^sd1.(domain1|domain2).com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sd1/.*
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  sd1/$1  [L]
```

Now this does forward the request to different folder but afterwards all the url have `sd1` attached on the last part

Here is an illustration

```
sd1.domain.com            ---> sd1.domain.com                 #Works correctly
sd1.domain.com/page1.html ---> sd1.domain.com/sd1/page1.html  # See the word sd1 on the middle
```

How to remove the folder portion from the url??

Comment: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: @Nileshpatel, What is your point?

Comment: may you got help from that. i tried but not success.

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess code? If not please dump your full .htaccess within your question since your code is obviously doing an internal forward only and that shouldn't change the URL in the browser.

Comment: @anubhava, Here is the full dump http://pastebin.com/vD3tas90

Comment: Is that the only .htaccess you have or you have .htaccess in sub directories as well? Also tell me what URL are you trying in your browser for testing?

Comment: @anubhava, Yes some hosted projects like joomla and drupal do have other htacceses. You can check www.ngentechnology.com its a basic drupal install.

Comment: Hmm Drupal, Joomla and Wordpress all are very particular about their structure of URLs and I suspect these frameworks might be doing an external redirect.

Comment: @anubhava, What kind of rule can cause this? How to solve it?

Comment: Not just rule these frameworks have their front controller logic built in framework itself and have pre-defined URL structure. If you deviate from that structure they do redirect from PHP code itself to conform to their URL scheme.

Comment: @anubhava, That does not seem to be the problem. On [this](http://clients.mrnepal.com/PrabinPoudel/merocampus/) simple HTML project also it is showing similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do it by using the flag PT (Passthru), which causes the rewrite target to be passed back to the URL mapping engine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^sd1.(domain1|domain2).com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sd1/.*
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  sd1/$1  [PT,L]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Startx, I saw http://ngentechnology.com/ was redirecting to http://ngentechnology.com/drupal previously. Now I see it remains on http://ngentechnology.com/. Any other url that I can test the behavior?

Comment: @Startx, I have taken a look at your live sites. As anubhava mentioned, the problem can be anywhere in Joomla or Drupal configuration settings or rewrite rules. I don't think it can be solved with a simple rewrite rules. You may need system administrator with access to your server to help investigate further.

Comment: @szemain, No its not the real problem, even if simple HTML project like [this](http://clients.mrnepal.com/PrabinPoudel/merocampus/) it redirects in the same way. It has no htaccess further down.

Comment: @Startx, the HTML project above has indeed links without /clients (such as http://clients.mrnepal.com/about), problem is it is unable to remap to http://clients.mrnepal.com/clients/about. This site has completely different issue compare than the one of Joomla and Drupal. Even simple HTML project might needs to change its base href, absolute and relative paths when you change your web hosting configuration.